# trying to insert a vector to an unordered_map but get "message : see reference to class template instantiation"

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I'm trying to make an ecs and this is my code

```cpp
#include "pandaFramework.h"
#include "pandaSystem.h"

#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include <iostream>

struct Component {
    NodePath* node_path;
    Component(NodePath* path) {
        node_path = path;
    }
    void start(){}
    void update(){}
};

struct Spinner : Component {
    void update() {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
};

class Scene : public NodePathCollection {
public:
    std::unordered_map<NodePath*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>> components;
    void add_path(NodePath node_path) {
        NodePathCollection::add_path(node_path);
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> empty;
        components[&node_path] = std::move(empty);
    }

    template<typename ComponentType>
    void add_component(NodePath* node_path) {
        components[node_path].push_back(std::make_unique<ComponentType>(node_path));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Load the window and set its title.

    PandaFramework framework;

    framework.open_framework(argc, argv);

    framework.set_window_title("My Panda3D Window");

    WindowFramework* window = framework.open_window();


    // Load the environment model.

    NodePath scene = window->load_model(framework.get_models(), "models/environment");

    Scene s;
    s.add_path(scene);
    s.add_component<Spinner>(&scene);

    // Reparent the model to render.

    scene.reparent_to(window->get_render());

    // Apply scale and position transforms to the model.

    scene.set_scale(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f);

    scene.set_pos(-8, 42, 0);


    // Run the engine.

    framework.main_loop();

    // Shut down the engine when done.

    framework.close_framework();

    return 0;

}
```

And when I use add_object I get
"message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vectorstd::unique_ptr<Component,std::default_delete<Component>,std::allocatorstd::unique_ptr<Component,std::default_delete<Component>>>' being compiled"
What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple fundamental bugs with the shown code.

You will get the same compilation error with the following code, as well:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> empty;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> empty2=empty;
```

A `std::unique_ptr`, by definition, a one and only pointer to the same underlying object. There are no others. For that reason is why `std::unique_ptr` does not have a copy constuctor. A `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied. This is an absolute rule. No exceptions. The above code attempts to copy a vector of `std::unique_ptr`s. Since they cannot be copied, this fails. The fact that, in this instance, the vectors are empty is immaterial.

```
    void add_object(Object object) {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> empty;
        components[&object] = empty;
    }
```

The assignment operator effectively attempts to make a copy of the vector, and this fails for the same reason.

It's possible to make this work using move semantics:

```
components[&object] = std::move(empty);
```

This will now compile. But now you have a different bug to deal with.

`object` is a parameter to this function.

When this function returns, all of its parameters get destroyed. They will no longer exist. They will cease to exist. They will become no more. They will be come ex-objects.

And the code above will be left with a pointer to a destroyed object in the unordered map. Whatever happens to touch that pointer, from that point on, by definition, will be undefined behavior. You will need to fix this as well.

Comment: Well, that worked. But now I have an other error which says "see reference to function template instantiation 'std::unique_ptr<Spinner,std::default_delete<Spinner>> std::make_unique<Spinner,NodePath*,0>(NodePath *&&)' being compiled"

Comment: Unfortunately there's no mention of any mysterious class named "Spinner" in your question, nor of `std::make_unique`, so I can't tell you anything about that. I can only answer what's asked in the question. The shown code compiles with `std::move` (after adding some includes and stub declarations). If you now have a different question, related to different parts of your code, you should post another question, with another [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste into a empty file, then attempt to compile and reproduce the same compilation error.

Comment: I editted the post and added struct spinner

Comment: If you actually take what's in your post now, copy/paste it into an empty file, add my fix, and the missing header files, the shown code will compile without any errors. There's nothing wrong with the additional shown code, therefore the problem must be in the code that's not shown. Nobody can possibly help you with code that's not shown. This is why you must follow the instructions in the Stackoverflow's [help] for creating a [mre]. Until everyone can cut/paste the shown code ***exactly as shown*** and reproduce your error, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Alright. I added all my code.

Comment: Please don't waste other people's time. The latest version of the shown code will not compile due to a missing header file, `pandaFramework.h`. Which part of creating a [mre] is unclear to you? If you don't take the time to put together an organized, prepared question, with all the information needed to answer it, other people won't take their time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very layered, as mentioned in Sam's answer. One problem is that you lack a proper copy constructor for the `Component` class. This can be solved by not using a temporary variable as shown in the code below:

```cpp
class Scene {
public:
    std::unordered_map<Object*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>> components;
    void add_object(Object object) {
        // std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> empty;
        // Adding an empty container at the given key
        components[&object] = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>();
    }
};
```

For the other problems Sam's mentions in his answers, perhaps, instead of using a pointer to an `Object`, you could use the `object` instead. This could also lead to the same copy constructor issue, but the code should work with minimal changes.

Comment: This is incorrect. `empty` is very much instantiated. It's not the instantiation that's the problem, but something entirely else: the fact that `unique_ptr`'s copy constructor is deleted.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. I'll edit the question with this new information.